# Verifying proof of Bolzano-Weierstass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Can anyone check this proof for being correct? (Also, suggestions on improvement are welcome). I know that I could've done this in much more condensed manner, but I tried to make an explicit construction and make it as much independent from other theorems as possible.

$\textbf{Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.}$ Any bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$ of real numbers contains a convergent subsequence.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $\{x_n\}$ be any bounded sequence of real numbers, that is, there are $m, M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$m \leq x_n \leq M$$
\Consider a sequence of partitions of $[m, M]$:
$$P_0 = \{m, M\}$$
$$P_1 = \{m, \frac{m+M}{2}, M\}$$
$$ \cdots$$
$$P_k = \{m, \frac{(2^k-1)m+M}{2^k}, \ldots, \frac{(2^k-j)m+jM}{2^k}, \ldots, \frac{m+(2^k-1)M}{2^k}, M\}$$
$$\cdots$$
With each partition $P_k$ we associate a sequence of segments $\{I_{j,k}\}$, $j = 1, \ldots, 2^k$, where
$$I_{j,k} =\left[\frac{(2^k-j+1)m+(j-1)M}{2^k}, \frac{(2^k-j)m+M}{2^k}\right]$$
We construct convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$. First, we choose from the segments $I_{1,1}$ and $I_{2,1}$ a segment containing infinitely many elements of sequence $\{x_n\}$ (clearly, there should be one) and associate with it a number $n_1$ such that $n_1$ is the minimal index of a term of $\{x_n\}$ contained in this segment. Once segment $I_{j,k}$ (containing infinitely many elements of $\{x_n\}$) and corresponding to it number $n_k$ are chosen, there are two segments $I_{l,k+1}, I_{l+1, k+1} \subset I_{jk}$. We choose from them one containing infinitely many terms of $\{x_n\}$ and associate with it a number $n_{k+1}$ to be a minimal index of a term of $\{x_n\}$ contained in this segment (also notice that by construction this $n_{k+1}$ is greater than all numbers chosen before).

We constructed a strictly increasing sequence $\{n_k\}$ of natural numbers and corresponding to it subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$  is convergent since for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $l > k$ we have
$$|x_{n_k}-x_{n_l}| < \frac{M-m}{2^{k-1}}$$
thus Cauchy criterion is obviously met. Or we could just observe that segments to which elements of our subsequence belong constitute sequence of nested segments of an arbitrary small length, thus having common point $L = \lim_{n_k \to \infty} x_{n_k}$

Comment: It looks correct to me.